# Trouble passing indexPath.row with prepareForSegue with UISearchBar

Tags: uitableview, uisearchbar, uistoryboardsegue

I'm having a dickens of a time getting this whole Core Data, Storyboard, UISearchBar trio working together as it should. Having finally successfully built the table with Core Data, narrow the items with a Search Text, and modified prepareForSegue, there is still one hiccup...

When I click on any item in the table to go to the detail view, all is fine in the unfiltered table. PrepareForSegue is called and the detail appears perfectly.

When I search, my table is filtered (I'm going to filtered array option for now instead of a second NSFetchedResultsController, but not for lack of trying!).

When I click on an item in the filtered list, prepareForSegue is called and the detail view is pushed, however, it always pulls the detail from the first item in the list!

For example, if I searched for "c" and the list was narrowed to "Charlie" and "Cookie", when I select "Charlie" I see the detail view for "Charlie". When I select "Cookie", I, unfortunately, also see the detail view for "Charlie"

I'm making the assumption that the prepareForSegue code is the issue (maybe incorrectly?). Here is the code:

```
    SampleTVC *sampleDetailTVC = segue.destinationViewController;
    sampleDetailTVC.delegate = self;

    // Store selected Role in selectedRole property
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
  //  self.selectedRole = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (savedSearchTerm){
        self.selectedRole = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    } else {
        self.selectedRole = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
    NSLog(@"Passing selected role (%@) to SampleTVC", self.selectedRole.name);
    sampleDetailTVC.role = self.selectedRole;
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: When you select "Cookie", can you log the values of `self.searchResults` and `indexPath.row` at the point where you get the role?

Comment: When I add: if (savedSearchTerm){
            self.selectedRole = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            NSLog(@"what are searchresults:%@   what is indexpath:%@", self.searchResults, indexPath.row);  -------------------- I get the following: what are searchresults:charlie, cookie [edited to shorten]   what is indexpath:(null)                           ----- I'm thinking that index.path (null) may be the issue?

Comment: and on the non-searched table, if I log indexPath I get: what is indexpath:<NSIndexPath 0x8960300> 2 indexes [0, 3]

Comment: Probably...a null index path likely gives zero as its row.  (I assume you're actually logging `indexPath` rather than `indexPath.row`.)

Comment: Your filtered list **is** being shown in the same table view as your full list, right?  Also, something else to try, if your segue is hooked to a table view cell as its source, you should be able to use `indexPathForCell:` and pass `sender` as the cell.

Comment: right, when I log indexPath from the searched table, I get (null) -- but from the regular table I get the correct indexPath -- so the NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableview indexPathForSelectedRow] must not be grabbing the data from the searched table... any thoughts on how to get it to retrieve the data? I know the searched table is it's own thing, and I was hoping self.tableview would be accessing it, but perhaps that is wrong. I've been using  UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; in the cellForRowAtIndexPath successfully...

Comment: If you're using `UISearchDisplayController`, we're getting past what I know about.  I've done filtered searches but then used my own table for displaying results.  I note however that the docs talk about `searchController.searchResultsTableView`; maybe that's what you should ask for the indexPath in the search case.  But I'm guessing.  :)

Comment: Ooooh... Interesting... When I nslog sender, It does distinguish between Charlie and Cookie as the text for the cell, but, when I add NSIndexPath *indexPath2 = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender]; I still get null... I'm clearly using the indexpathforcell incorrectly

Comment: Ahh! Phillip, you did it! I added this: indexPath = [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView indexPathForSelectedRow]; for the indexPath inside the (savedSearchterm) and it seems to be working! I could kiss you, but that seems wildly inappropriate. Instead, you'll have to be satisfied with knowing you have saved me from hours of additional headaches...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thanks to Phillip Mills, for the answer:

just simply had to add:

```
    indexPath = [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
```

full sample:

```
    SampleTVC *sampleDetailTVC = segue.destinationViewController;
    sampleDetailTVC.delegate = self;
     // Store selected Role in selectedRole property
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    //  self.selectedRole = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (savedSearchTerm){
         indexPath = [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    self.selectedRole = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    } else {
        self.selectedRole = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
     }
    NSLog(@"Passing selected role (%@) to SampleTVC", self.selectedRole.name);
    sampleDetailTVC.role = self.selectedRole;
```

Comment: Thanks!, it won't let me for another 17 hours... :)